# JSON Object parsing containing nested JSON strings

Tags: json

I am really strgulling to parse this from JSONObject.

```
   res=  {
       "ldap-container":
       {
           "@id": "1",
           "@name": "easyas",
           "@last-accessed": "2014-07-12T02:11:19.327Z",
           "@active": "true",
           "primary-ldap":
           {
               "@ldap-alias": "easyAs",
               "@ldap-query": "(cn=*)",
               "@resource-name-attributes": "givenname"
           }
       }
    }


JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(res);
String root = jsonObject.getString("ldap-container");
```

I want to access each and every name value pair. Tried JSONParser but couldn't, tried JSONArray and as it's not an array, I couldn't obviously.

Any pointers would be greatly welcome, thanks

Comment: That's plain old JSON -- nothing special.  It's an "object" containing an "object" containing another "object" -- no arrays.  Go to json.org and learn the syntax (takes 5-10 minutes), and then it will make more sense.

Comment: And if you want to see what keys are in an object, the org.json version of JSONObject has a static method `getNames` which will return an array of key names.  But if you know the names, just use `jsonObject.getString`, etc, to get values from the "object".

Answer (score 0):

`ldap-container` is an object not a String, here is how you parse that json:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(res);
JSONObject root = jsonObject.getJSONObject("ldap-container");

String alias = root.getString("@id");//1

JSONObject primary = root.getJSONObject("primary-ldap");
String alias = primary.getString("@ldap-alias");//easyAs
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var res =  {
           "ldap-container":
           {
               "@id": "1",
               "@name": "easyas",
               "@last-accessed": "2014-07-12T02:11:19.327Z",
               "@active": "true",
               "primary-ldap":
               {
                   "@ldap-alias": "easyAs",
                   "@ldap-query": "(cn=*)",
                   "@resource-name-attributes": "givenname"
               }
           }
        }

    var id = res["ldap-container"]["@id"]

    var alias = res["ldap-container"]["primary-ldap"]["@ldap-alias"]
```